# How do I capitalize the first letter of a string if it is not one already?

Tags: java, string

I need to convert the first letter of a String into a Capital if it is not already one for part of a project of mine.  Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please share what you have tried or done.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this,

```
  String str= "haha";
  str.replaceFirst("\\w", str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s = "this is my string";
s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, this replaces every alpha-numeric word (plus underscores) so its first character is uppercase:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b([a-z])(\\w+)").matcher(str);

StringBuffer bfr = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find())  {
   m.appendReplacement(bfr,
      m.group(1).toUpperCase() + "$2");
}
m.appendTail(bfr);
```

It does not alter words that are already uppercased.